# Log4J not working properly?

Tags: java, log4j

I am new to Log4J. i am trying to get this logger to work. i downloaded the .JAR file and I have built that into the Referenced Libraries and can open the folder and see it in there. So I think it is built into my project.

I think that I am missing how to declare the logger so that i can use it below. Some of the code I got from stackoverflow.

**Question: Which part of the Log4J declaration am I missing so that I can use it as a logger in my simple example?**

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestLogs {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileChooserDemo.class.getName());

    FileHandler fh;   

    public TestLogs() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); 
            fh = new FileHandler("C:\\Users\\itpr13266\\Desktop\\MyNewLogFile.log");   
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            logger.info("Logging an INFO-level message");
            logger.warning("Your file cannot be written!!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileChooserDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void LogTester() {
         Logger.getRootLogger().getLoggerRepository().resetConfiguration();
         ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
          //configure the appender
          String PATTERN = "%d [%p|%c|%C{1}] %m%n";
          console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN)); 
          console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
          console.activateOptions();
          //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
          Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);

          FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
          fa.setName("FileLogger");
          fa.setFile("mylog.log");
          fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
          fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
          fa.setAppend(true);
          fa.activateOptions();

          //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
          Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa)    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       TestLogs tls = new TestLogs();
       tls.LogTester();
     }
}
```

[image]

new image- I rebuilt the paths and it put them in a slightly different position in the file structure. But the error still persists.

[image]

Code that works --- But how do I log it to a text file on my computer.

```
package TestMenu;

import org.apache.log4j.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestLogs {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestLogs.class.getName());

    public TestLogs() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    private void LogTester() {
         logger.info("It works");
         TestLogs tls = new TestLogs();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       TestLogs tls = new TestLogs();
       tls.LogTester();
     }
}
```

At least the log4j is working but how to change the properties file around so that I can log all warnings, info and to a file not to the console?

Log4j Properties:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

new image -- not working -- error shown on bottom

[image]

[image]

Errors:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (TestMenu.TestLogs).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

[image]

Comment: see the sample I added. I hope it helps. It needs that you have log4j.jar in your path

Comment: Ok, I am not certain how to add the file appender.

Comment: Check the updated log4j.properties in my answer

Comment: Did, changed it in my file. and I still get an error. Listed above in my example.

Comment: That means for some reason it's not picking up the log4j.properties file. Usually a clean build fixes the issue.

Comment: Cleaned it and nothing. Still same errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52543/discussion-between-vkg-and-doug-hauf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use java util logging not log4j.
you need to import

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

Another thing I see that is wrong in your code is

**change this:**

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileChooserDemo.class.getName());
```

**To**

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestLogs.class.getName());
```

**Here is a sample**

```
package com.vkg;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLogs {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestLogs.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("It works");
        TestLogs tls = new TestLogs();
    }
}
```

**A basic log4j config file**

```
  # Root logger 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Write to file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=[sompath to your log file e.g. C:\\mylog.log]
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Write to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**And output**

```
2014-05-12 13:18:01 INFO  TestLogs:9 - It works
```

**Image below shows where to keep log4j.properties**

[image]

Comment: It does not like my import but the file is there. I will put an image in the question above.

Comment: I also updated the image to show where my log4j.jar is. I would suggest try to do a project > clean > build from eclipse see if that solves your issue. Or I another thing you can do is make sure your build path in eclipse is good and that that jar is actually present. Right click on your project go to properties > Java Build Path> Libraries make sure every thing looks good there and no errors.

Comment: Did you try deleting the java.util.logging imports. I will suggest try removing those.

Answer (score 1):

You should be importing `org.apache.log4j.Logger`, and nothing from `java.util.logging`.

Comment: That was for the other logger that Java provides. Can you put up a code example of everything that should be needed for this?

Comment: How do you add the file location for the logger file and what about the appender?